# Form validation when two inputs are in the same line in an Angular 6 application

Tags: html, css, angular, validation

I am implementing a form using Angular 6 and html. There, I have 2 input fields in the same line.

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="input-name" class="sr-only">First name</label>
    <input class="registerInput2"
           type="text"
           nbInput
           [(ngModel)]="user.firstName"
           #firstName="ngModel"
           id="input-fname"
           name="firstName"
           placeholder="First name"
           autofocus
           fullWidth
           [required]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.required')"
           [minlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.minLength')"
           [maxlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.maxLength')">
    <span class="iconSan"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    <small class="form-text error" *ngIf="firstName.invalid && firstName.touched && firstName.errors?.required">
      First name is required!
    </small>
    <small
      class="form-text error"
      *ngIf="firstName.invalid && firstName.touched && (firstName.errors?.minlength || firstName.errors?.maxlength)">
      First name should contains
      from {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.minLength')}}
      to {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.firstName.maxLength')}}
      characters
    </small>

  <label for="input-name" class="sr-only">Last name</label>
  <input class="registerInput2"
      type="text"
      nbInput [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" 
      #lastName="ngModel" 
      id="input-lname" 
      name="lastName" 
      placeholder="Last name" 
      autofocus
      fullWidth [required]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.required')" 
      [minlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.minLength')"
      [maxlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.maxLength')"
      [status]="email.dirty ? (email.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''">
    <span class="iconSan"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
  <small class="form-text error" *ngIf="lastName.invalid && lastName.touched && lastName.errors?.required">
    Last name is required!
  </small>
  <small class="form-text error" *ngIf="lastName.invalid && lastName.touched && (lastName.errors?.minlength || lastName.errors?.maxlength)">
    Last name should contains from {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.minLength')}} to {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.lastName.maxLength')}}
    characters
  </small>
</div>
```

I have set style for the firstName as 'float-left' and for the lastName as 'float-right'. But when my input fields give validation messages it changes the UI. For example, If the 'firstName' field gives a validation message, 'lastName' field goes down. I searched the internet a lot about the problem but did not get any solution. The below image shows the error.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgOhV.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While using small with input is pretty striaghtforward and easy, I would recommend you to use Angular Material library written specifically for angular, but only if you haven't created bootstrap as a dependency of your project yet because angular material and bootstrap doesn't work well together. With that being said and assuming you would go for angular material, the solution to your layout problems are over.

Instead of using **div** tag, you would use **mat-form-field** and instead of **small**, you would use **mat-error**, you don't have to change any logic for that, just the tags. The angular material dependency will take care of the layout and styling issues.

Take a look at the documentation, if you are an angular guy, I'm sure you'll love it:
https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview